# Boto3 Cloudwatch alarm create new instance

Tags: boto3, google-colaboratory, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to create a Boto3 Cloudwatch alarm that fires when the CPU utilization is higher than a certain threshold 5 consecutive times and when it fires it creates a new instance. So far I have the code to create the alarm but I don't know how to implement creating the new instance.

```
# Create alarm to fire when the load for the baseline is over 50% 5 consecutive times
results = client.put_metric_alarm(
    AlarmName='CPU_Utilization',
    ComparisonOperator='GreaterThanThreshold',
    EvaluationPeriods=5,
    MetricName='CPUUtilization',
    Namespace='AWS/EC2',
    Period=60,
    Statistic='Maximum',
    Threshold=50.0,
    ActionsEnabled=False,
    AlarmDescription='CPU exceeds 50% for 5 consecutive times',
    Dimensions=[
        {
          'Name': 'InstanceId',
          'Value': 'i-XXXXXXXXXX'
        },
    ],
    Unit='Percent'
)
```

As part two, how can I delete the new instance that was created if the load falls below a certain threshold?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/as-scale-based-on-demand.html

Comment: @jordanm I don't see where in the documentation it talks about creating/terminating new instances based on a condition